# Remove class of last element in element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to remove the class of the last list item. But jQuery only removes the class of both list items after 2 clicks.

What am i doing wrong here? Why does jQuery not remove only the last class? And if only one list item with this class exist, just remove this class.

```js
$( "#test" ).click(function() {
  $("ul li.visible").last().removeClass( "visible" );
});
```

```css
a {
  color:blue;
}
.visible {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="test">Click me -> Remove last</a>
<ul>
  <li>Bla
    <ul>
      <li class="visible">Foo
        <ul>
          <li class="visible"> Bar</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what do you mean by last class? You want to remove all the last children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It **is** removing the class from the last element that has it. But that element is **inside** another element that also has the class, so it inherits the styling (`color: red`). This becomes obvious if you do something like border:

```js
$( "#test" ).click(function() {
  $("ul li.visible").last().removeClass( "visible" );
});
```

```css
a {
  color:blue;
}
.visible {
  color:red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="test">Click me -> Remove last</a>
<ul>
  <li>Bla
    <ul>
      <li class="visible">Foo
        <ul>
          <li class="visible"> Bar</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you don't want the descendant elements to inherit the styling, you'll have to modify your CSS. For instance, you could have `ul` elements styled with `color: black`:

```js
$( "#test" ).click(function() {
  $("ul li.visible").last().removeClass( "visible" );
});
```

```css
a {
  color:blue;
}
ul {
  color: black;
}
.visible {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="test">Click me -> Remove last</a>
<ul>
  <li>Bla
    <ul>
      <li class="visible">Foo
        <ul>
          <li class="visible"> Bar</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct. Check by changing the nested elements color.
The problem is that nested child inherits parent styling by default. Though class *active* got removed, the last element is still red as it's a part of other element with class *active*

```js
$( "#test" ).click(function() {
  $("ul li.visible").last().removeClass( "visible" );
});
```

```css
a {
  color:blue;
}
.visible {
  color:red;
}
.visible .visible{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="test">Click me -> Remove last</a>
<ul>
  <li>Bla
    <ul>
      <li class="visible">Foo
        <ul>
          <li class="visible"> Bar</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```